# При выводе нескольких строк из MySQL посредством PHP в JSON попадает только первая строка

Tags: json, json-encode

Есть база данных MySQL с соответствующими разделам будущего JSON файла строками. Их для примера две. (Это данные для API Яндекс.Карт, если кому интересно).
Вытаскиваю данные, чтобы сформировать из них массив нужного вида, и затем загнать его в JSON файл:

```
public function makeFile()
{
   $point_data = array();
   $res        = mysqlQuery("SELECT * FROM points;"); 
   while($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
   {
        $point_data = [
          "type"     => $row['type'],
          "features" => [[
                "type"     => $row['type1'],
                "id"       => $row['id'],
                "geometry" => [
                      "type"        => $row['type2'], 
                      "coordinates" => [
                                     $row['x'],
                                     $row['y']
                                       ],
                              ],
                       "properties" => [
                                     "balloonContentHeader" => 
                                      $row['balloonContentHeader'],
                                     "balloonContentBody"   => 
                                      $row['balloonContentBody'],
                                      "balloonContentFooter"=> 
                                      $row['balloonContentFooter'],
                                      "clusterCaption"      => 
                                      $row['clusterCaption'],
                                      "hintContent"         => 
                                      $row['hintContent']
                                       ]
                          ]]
            ];
    }
    return $point_data;
```

После чего с полученным массивом собираю JSON-файл.

```
    $filename = "data.json";
    file_put_contents($filename, json_encode($point_data));
```

Но в итоге, JSON файл содержит данные только из первой строки MySQL базы.
Если в итоге файл получаю, значит код работает, промах в логике. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Думаю попадает не первая, а последняя строка. потому что на каждой итерации цикла вы присваиваете $point_data абсолютно новое значение, которое затирает предыдущее

Comment: Но каким образом добиться чтобы формируемый циклом массив не затирал предыдущее значение, а дополнял его последующим? Все материалы, имеющиеся на эту тему тожеиспользуют соответствующий цикл. Просматривая получившийся массив, вижу что там отражены данные всех строк, а после json_encode остается только одна

Comment: Это зависит от того, что такое "дополнял". как в итоговом json должна быть представлена эта информация. Если например в виде массива записей с указанной структурой, то перед циклом сделать `$point_data=array();` а в цикле добавлять строки в этот массив `$point_data[] = ...`